# .Net Cloud Based Storage solution

Tags: c#, web-hosting, cloud-platform

I am now at the point where i cant get any further with out some help.I am trying to host files on the cloud and then access those files via code (C#). So far i have tried Rapidshare and Skydrive and have been unable to get either working at all. Below is a few things that i am trying to do or rather must be able to do with the cloud storage.

1. What i need is a place to host files on the internet (obvious).
2. The files can range in size from 10 megs to 100megs.
3. I Must be able to download the files via code as well as upload via code.

I don't really mind having to pay as long as the price is not ridiculous.Any help at all will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Stalkerh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you look at [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) they do what you want, are cheap and have a C# API wrapping their web service (But [ThreeSharp](http://www.codeplex.com/ThreeSharp) is better).

Comment: Thanks will give it a go but it looks like what i need